# python's imports doesn't support unittesting

Tags: python, python-2.7, import, python-unittest, relative-import

I have the following directories tree (Python 2.7):

```
./pkg
    ./main.py
    ./A
        ./a.py
    ./B
        ./b.py
    ./C
        ./c.py
```

a.py, b.py and c.py need to import each other, so I have two options:

1. **use relative imports**, which means I have to start the program from ./pkg/main.py or another file from the top of the directory tree.
   That is really good and all,  but the problem starts when I write a test to one of those files. I can't write a test in ./main/A that imports a.py, because a.py wouldn't be able to use b.py and c.py, so the only way is to write the test functions on ./main.
2. to add to **sys.path** the absulote path of ./main in each of the files. that means I have to write the same three line for all of the files, and if I have 300 files instead of 3, that's a pain (and most likely, not best parctice).

So, what should I do?

Comment: Would adding `./pkg` (as an absolute path) to `PYTHONPATH` do what you want? PS. do you have `__init__.py` files in your package directories?

Comment: This is why tests are generally in a separate directory at the top level of your project, allowing them to be run from above `pkg`. This means that the tests are actually exercising your package how it will be used in practice.

Comment: yes, there is a `__init__`.py in `./pkg`. Even if the tests are in a separated directory, if I start by running a single test, it would not be able to go the other directories.

Comment: @YanayTevet *"it would not be able to go the other directories"* - what? Why not? What's the *actual error* you're getting? If you have `__init__.py` files, show them. Have a look at e.g. http://www.jeffknupp.com/blog/2013/08/16/open-sourcing-a-python-project-the-right-way/ for a sensible project structure.

Answer (score 0):

Use relative imports.

If pkg is your project's root path, use:

```
python -m unittest A.a
```

to make import work.